# Command line argument is not working for "grep" command in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
#! /bin/bash


grep -oh \w*ings "${1}"
```

while the above command is working in terminal, I can't figure  out the problem in script

I'm trying to find all the words in the file that are ending with 'ing'

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want the `*` to be glob expanded?  Does the current working directory of the script contain files that match that glob?  Have you tried `grep -oh 'w*ings' "${1}"`?

Comment: i'm trying to find the words that ends with ing in the given file. I tried grep -oh 'w*ings' "${1}" and it was not working

Comment: `w*ings` matches strings (in your case, because of `-w´, full words) which contain zero or more occurances of the letter `w`, followed by `ings`. It would match `ings` or `wwwwwingx`, but not `xwings`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `grep`, the string `w*ings` is a regex. To the shell, the string `w*ings` is a glob.  The string `\w*ings` is a glob with an escaped `w`.  The shell will take the string `\w*ings` and convert it to `w*ings`, and then (I'm not actually sure about the order here; we can check the documentation but it's not important) it will look in the current directory to see if that glob matches any files.  If there are multiple files in the directory, it will expand to them.  eg, if you have the files `waings` and `wbings`, then the shell will pass both as arguments to grep.  Assuming `$1` expands to `foo`, `grep` will get the arguments: `-oh`, `waings`, `wbings`, and `foo` exactly as if you had invoked `grep -oh waings wbings foo`.  This is almost certainly not what you want.  You probably intended to pass the literal string `\w*ings` to `grep`, so you ought to have done:

```
grep -oh '\w*ings' "${1}"
```

But from your comment, it sounds like you actually want to do something like:

```
 grep -o '[[:<:]][_[:alnum:]]*ing[[:>:]]' "${1}"
```

or

```
grep -ow '[_[:alnum:]]*ing' "${1}"
```

(`-w` is equivalent to wrapping the pattern in `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`)

Comment: I tried this grep -oh '\w*ings' "${1}" and it is not working.    I want to find all the words in a file that ends with 'ing'

Comment: @RaviTejaReddy It is working, it just isn't doing what you want.  You need to describe (in the question, not in comments) the behavior that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This would be

```
grep -oh '.*wings'  "$1"
```

Comment: Actually i'm trying to find all the words that are ending with 'ing' in the file

Comment: Then just adapt my solution to this: Use `.*ing`  as a pattern.